# Combining data from two repositories MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, repository

I am trying to combine the data from two repositories in MVC4. I am using a join statement in my Action function to gather information from two tables. I am passing this this data onto my view. I am a little confused to how to correctly combine the data from the two repositories. Some help would be appreciated. THANKS!

In controller:

```
 public IOwnerRepository OwnerDB;
 public IDwellingRepository DwellingDB;
 public OwnerController() : this(new OwnerRepository(), new DwellingRepository()) {}
 public OwnerController(IOwnerRepository oRepository, IDwellingRepository dRepository)
 {
     OwnerDB    = oRepository;
     DwellingDB = dRepository;
 }
```

Action:

```
public ActionResult Account(int id, int? activelink)
{
    // Link values
    // Account         = 0
    // Listings        = 1
    // Profile         = 2
    // Create Property = 3
    // Check for a value
    // If no value set to zero
    if (!activelink.HasValue)
        activelink = 0;
    // ####ing hackers
    if (activelink > 3)
        activelink = 0;
    ViewBag.ActiveLink = activelink.ToString();
    switch (activelink)
    {
        case 0:
            ViewBag.Title = "Account Details";
        break;
        case 1:
            ViewBag.Title = "Listings";
        break;
        case 2:
            ViewBag.Title = "Profile";
        break;
        case 3:
            ViewBag.Title = "Create Property";
        break;
    }
    var oOwner = OwnerDB.FindOne(GetUserId(), id);
    if (oOwner == null)
    {
    return new FileNotFoundResult { Message = "No Account found for id " + id.ToString() };
    }
    else
    {
    return View(oOwner);
    }
}
```

Owner Repository:

```
public Owner FindOne(string UserId, int id)
    {
      var dwelling = (from o in db.Owner 
                    join d in db.Dwelling on o.ID equals d.Owner_ID into ps
                    from k in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select o );
      var oOwner = (from p in dwelling
                    where p.ID == id
                    select p);
      return oOwner.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question you need to ask yourself is: Do I need those 2 repositories?
Does it make sens in your domain definition to have both of them? Does `Dwelling` make sense without an `Owner` and vice versa?

One of the DDD best practices is to limit one repository per aggregate root. Have a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158064/reducing-repositories-to-aggregate-roots) where someone was wondering if there was a need to build both `User` and `Phone` repostories.

If you do need to have separate repositories then you might have to consider adding a `Service` layer on top of them.

Please have a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181290/decouple-unit-of-work-from-services-or-repo/15527444#15527444) where I answered someone how to decouple things (there's a `Unit of Work` pattern in this example but it doesn't matter)

Comment: Wow "I was blind, but now I can see". Thank you very much! Awesome read.